# Flutter encrypt - AES result is not the same in java

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, encryption, aes

I'm trying to decode a Uint8list in kotlin previously encrypted in flutter, but the decryption is not correct, i'm probably doing something wrong but I can't find what, could you help me ?

**Context :**

the key and the IV are constants for the moment and are 128bits, so pointyCatle should use AES128 and I should be able to decrypt it with the same key and IV

**Example**

with mainkey = 11112222 33344444

```
Uint8List mainKey = Uint8List.fromList([0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02,
  0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x04, 0x04, 0x04, 0x04, 0x04]);
var SessionCipher=new AESEncryptor();
...
var MainCipher=new AESEncryptor();
MainCipher.setIV(SessionCipher.getIv());
MainCipher.setKey(mainKey);
var encryptedSessionKey = MainCipher.encrypt(SessionCipher.getKey());
```

and iv = 00000000 00000000

data is a secureRandom generated Key

- input :{ad,11,b4,6b,61,69,5f,e9,12,e7,05,35,b8,95,3a,09}
- encrypted input : {0x2C, 0xC3, 0x81, 0xE9, 0x68, 0xD2, 0x83, 0x30, 0xF7, 0xA9, 0x5C, 0x4F, 0x67, 0x06, 0x3F, 0x5B}
- encrypt decryption :    {ad,11,b4,6b,61,69,5f,e9,12,e7,05,35,b8,95,3a,09} GOOD
- javax.crypto decryption : {0x30, 0xAB, 0xEF, 0x34, 0x95, 0x75, 0x9D, 0x96, 0xE9,0x23, 0x7E, 0xE6, 0x64, 0x77, 0xF4, 0xD0} BAD

Both use the same key and IV, both are in CBC/no-padding

Could it come from the libraries that use a different algorithm ?
Am I doing something wrong ?

**Temporary Dart encryption class**

```
import 'package:ble_connect/utils/ble/FrameBuilder.dart';
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

IV newIV() {
  // return IV.fromLength(16);
  return(IV.fromBase16("00000000000000000000000000000000"));
}

class AESEncryptor {
  var iv;
  var encrypter;
  var key;

  AESEncryptor() {
    this.key = Key.fromSecureRandom(16);
    this.iv = newIV();
    this.encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc, padding: null));
  }

  void setIV(iv) {
    this.iv = iv;
  }

  IV getIv() {
    return (this.iv);
  }

  void setKey(key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  Key getKey() {
    return (this.key);
  }
  
  //encrypt method meant to encrypt a 128bits List or 128bits Key
  //input : data (Key or Uint8List of length 16)

  dynamic encrypt(data) {
    print("iv is : ${this.iv.base16}");
    if (data.runtimeType == Key) {
      data = toInt(combineByTwo(data.base16.split(''))); //convert a Key to a list of bytes (UGLY) 
    //additional info : data (Key) is converted to hex String by .base16 
    //then converted to list of char by .split('') 
    //then the elements of the list are grouped by two (in order to get bytes at the end ex : [f,f]-->[ff] 
    //finaly parsed to become a list of in values between 0-255
    }
    return encrypter.encryptBytes(data, iv: this.iv);
  }

}
```

Thank you for your help !

**EDIT :**
Encrypt library : https://github.com/leocavalcante/encrypt

**Kotlin code**

```
private object AES128{
    private fun cipher(opmode: Int, secretKey: ByteArray, iv: IvParameterSpec):Cipher{
        val c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding")
        val sk = SecretKeySpec(secretKey, "AES")
        c.init(opmode, sk, iv)
        return c
    }
    fun encrypt(byteArray: ByteArray, secretKey: ByteArray, iv: IvParameterSpec): ByteArray? {
        return cipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv).doFinal(padFrame(byteArray))
    }
    fun decrypt(byteArray: ByteArray, frameDataLength: Int, secretKey: ByteArray, iv: IvParameterSpec):ByteArray?{
        return unpadFrame(cipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv).doFinal(byteArray), frameDataLength)
    }

    private fun padFrame(frame: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        // MANUAL PADDING
        println(frame.size)
        val remain = (frame.size % 16).also {
            println(it)
        }
        if (remain != 0) {
            println("padding")
            val paddedValue = ByteArray(frame.size + 16 - remain)
            System.arraycopy(frame, 0, paddedValue, 0, frame.size)
            for (i in 0 until 16 - remain) {
                paddedValue[frame.size + i] = 0x0F
            }
            return paddedValue
        }
        println("not padding")
        return frame
    }

    private fun unpadFrame(frame: ByteArray, frameDataLength: Int): ByteArray {
        if(frameDataLength > 5) {
            val unpaddedValue = ByteArray(frameDataLength)
            System.arraycopy(frame, 0, unpaddedValue, 0, frameDataLength)
            return unpaddedValue
        }
        return frame
    }
}
```

Comment: AES/CBC must be the same regardless the implementing technology. From the code it is not visible what the "Encrypter is doing", no java code to compare. And btw the padding is done wrong way

Comment: It looks like you haven't specified which AES you want to use, and are just using whatever the default is. I'd imagine the default is different between dart and java. Try specifying the AES version to be the same in both implementations.

Comment: I will redo the padding but it does not affect the result because I use only 128bits  words, concerning the default mode its automatically chosen by encrypt (it's based on another library called pointycastle) depending of the length of the key
My key is 128bits long so if all is working fine it should not be a problem

Comment: What type does `data` have in `encrypt()` and `decrypt()`? Why the methods `combineByTwo()`, `recompose()`? The Dart code seems unnecessarily complicated to me. If you would post test data plus method calls (and not just the definitions), it would probably become clearer what you are actually trying to do. If the padding doesn't matter at the moment, skip it, as it's buggy and therefore just distracting.

Comment: thank you all for your comments I've edited my question with your comments and rephrase the begining for clarity

Comment: The `encrypter` object is created in the `AESEncryptor` constructor with a _random_ key. Therefore, `mainKey` passed in the `setKey`-call is _never_ used for encryption. Also: Why don't you just omit the `toInt(combineByTwo(...))` thing and apply `return encrypter.encryptBytes(data.bytes, iv: this.iv)`? After all, `data` is a `Key` object and `data.bytes` the key data as `Uint8List`.